# how do i show part number like given below in angular 4,i want to enter char like below in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

i want to enter char like below in angular 4.

**SDVC-RING-78521453F**

[image]

Comment: Read [ask] a question and provide a [mcve]

Comment: please add some of your code and say what you already tried.

Comment: You need a regex constraint for that?

Answer (score 0):

Try ngPrime they have input fields for stuff like this. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/inputmask

Comment: No idea, just knew that they had input fields like that, never worked with it.